# I want to use TOR or browse anonymously using puppeteer, Is there a way to do that without mutating chromium?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, tor

(WINDOWS)

I want to browse anonymously easily using puppeteer without mutating chromium.
I've read some articles (which there wasn't much of) and I couldn't understand.

Answer (score 1):

I think that should work

```
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({

     args: [ '--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:9050' ]

  });
```